# An adjective to describe someone with strong interpersonal skills?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am writing a letter of recommendation for a student who has strong interpersonal skills. In order to list that characteristic in parallel with others of her strengths, I would like an adjective. Specifically, I would like to say: "She is academically excellent, hardworking, and _____."

I thought of the word "personable", but that means having a pleasant personality or appearance. If she were manipulative, I could describe her as "Machiavellian", but I believe she uses her powers for good. What I mean to communicate is that she is a good listener, communicates well, and has good social skills.

**Update**

I chose not to use words like "sociable" or "gregarious" because I wish to emphasize her ability to communicate effectively in professional contexts. I am nominating her for a position that requires professional and academic excellence, not charm or even charisma. Think of qualities that would be admired in a great leader (of any gender).

Comment: Your interest in the post is welcome. You may not have known, though, that the comment thread is reserved for *helping to improve the post*: friendly clarifying questions, suggestions for improving the question, relevant but transient information, and explanations of your actions. Please avoid discussion, debate, or giving answers in comments. A welcoming place for discussion of posts (or anything else) is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Answer (score 1):

All of your clues are about interacting with people.  People make up a society.  You got close with 'good social skills'.  She is **sociable**.

Comment: Great answer, but for the OP's sake, please provide a link to an accredited dictionary.

Comment: I considered that word, but it seems to be defined as friendly, affable, gregarious, etc. There are many friendly students on campus. I do not mean that she is a socialite. I mean that she can communicate effectively in professional situations.

Comment: OK, then *communicative*

Answer (score 0):

> **approachable**, adjective
>   : capable of being approached : ACCESSIBLE
>   specifically : easy to meet or deal with

<sup>https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/approachable</sup>

Though there are some connotations to this word that would imply the positive notion of "strong interpersonal skills". If you were aiming for a more negative light (as in a salesperson that is good at using strong interpersonal skills to manipulate people), you may head towards:

> **sly**, adjective
>   1 chiefly dialectal
>   a : wise in practical affairs
>   b : displaying cleverness : INGENIOUS
>   <sup>https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sly</sup>